# Grails belongsTo relationship mechanism

Tags: grails

In a Grails relationship when an `Owner` domain class owns an `Owned` domain class, I've seen this declared two different ways in the `Owned` domain class:

```
static belongsTo [ owner : Owner ]
```

and sometimes as

```
static belongsTo [ Owner ]
```

what is the difference between these two other than the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is being able to indicate the name of the owned by property. In the second case it's going to assume the bean name convention of the class `owner` where as the first you are being explicit about the name of the property.

It's about flexibility. The first option is there if the second doesn't do what you intend or want.

Answer (score 4):

The first is bidirectional, since you have an instance of `Owner` defined in your class. The key of that map is typically the lowercase name of the domain class, but it can be any legal variable name. An AST transformation adds a property to your domain class (you can see this by decompiling the .class file), basically

```
Owner owner
```

or

```
Owner theOwner
```

if you had declared the `belongsTo` as

```
static belongsTo = [theOwner: Owner]
```

Don't add this yourself though - it's already there in the bytecode.

This is similar to declaring a `hasMany`, where the key of that map defines a collection (by default a `Set` but optionally a `List`). E.g. declaring

```
static hasMany = [owned: Owned]
```

creates the equivalent of

```
Set<Owned> owned
```

in the bytecode.

The second isn't bidirectional since there's no direct way to get to the owning instance.

Directionality has an impact on the table structure. In the first, you get what you probably expect - an `owner_id` column in the `Owned` domain class table which is a foreign key to the `Owner` domain class table. But in the second, there isn't a domain class property to associate with a foreign key, so in that case a third table is created to be the join table, similar to what happens for a many-to-many relationship.

I find that the `schema-export` script is very helpful for stuff like this. For each variant of the syntax, run

```
grails compile
grails schema-export
```

and view the contents of `target/ddl.sql` to see the resulting table structure for your domain classes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and especially the schema-export option.

Answer (score 2):

it's as simple as that: 
if you define the

```
static belongsTo = [ owner : Owner ]
```

then you can can access the `owner` as a variable: `obj.owner`. If you write:

```
static belongsTo = [ Owner ]
```

then you can't (you will get NoSuchPropException I guess).

In both cases the foreign-key relation is created